# Save data at parse.com it gives error "P_ID must be objectId not an NSString type"

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two tables at my parse account "Products" and "Orders". When I save data in "Orders" table I need "P_ID" which is the objectId of "Products" table. Can anybody tell me how I get this id using object.

I have no issue fetching the products but when I set order objects it gives error see the below code :

`PFObject *orders = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Orders"]; [orders setObject: object.productID objectForKey:@"P_ID"]; [order setObject:object.quantity objectForKey:@"Qty"];` 
 and then 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' block code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got answer of my question. For saving data in "Orders" I need object of "Products" class which I got from below code:

```
PFObject * products = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Products" objectId:productObj.productID];
```

In above code 'productObj.productID' is objectId of products in NSString type. then I simply set object in orders like below.

```
PFObject *orders = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Orders"]; 
[orders setObject: products objectForKey:@"P_ID"]; 
[order setObject:@(object.quantity) objectForKey:@"Qty"];
```

'@(object.quantity)' is an integer value which I saved in orders table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [documentation on Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide) about saving and querying objects, they have really good tutorials/examples/explanations.

Also, your statement is wrong :

> When I save data in "Orders" table I need "P_ID" which is the objectId of "Products" table.

It's not the object ID of the table, I think you meant the object ID of your product object. But that's not the question.

Now you need to fetch all your products, I'm guessing.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Products"];

//You can filter the query, to only get some of the products
//[query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Vegetable"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

  if (!error) {

    // The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d products.", objects.count);

    // Do something with the found objects
    //These are all your products. 
    //You can store in an array, a database, anything. 
    //Here we simply log all the objectIds in the console, 
    //you could   manipulate them as you wish. 

    for (PFObject *product in objects) {

        NSLog(@"%@", product.objectId);

    }

  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }

}];
```

We assume you have product(s) now, lets say it's a `PFObject` named `theProduct`.

Now, you want an new Order object that needs to be saved :

```
PFObject *order = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Order"];
order[@"totalPrice"] = @1337;
order[@"P_ID"] = theProduct.objectId;

[order saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (succeeded) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}];
```

Comment: #Zil I have updated my question please tell me if you have any solution. thanks